# python program killed in pbs without info

Tags: python, rpy2, qsub

I'm running a simple Python program using rpy2 in a cluster managed by pbs_torque. My problem is that the same piece of code works perfectly and other times is killed without logical reason or error trace. At random points during the execution of the program, the execution finishes. The only output error I get is this:

> kill: 20: No such process

I do not need to mention, that I'm not printing that message. Some output error files even contain this message several times. I've done some search but I have not found any relevant help. All the nodes of the cluster have the same configuration, and are supposed to run one instance of the program per core.

Suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: That error message looks like it's coming from [kill](http://linux.die.net/man/2/kill), and is saying there is no process to kill - this time. That suggests to me that sometimes it may be successful - and kills your job. I wonder if there is some kind of system monitoring process running on your cluster, which invokes `kill` under certain conditions (large memory usage, long idle times, long run times...?).

Comment: As far as I know there is no additional monitoring system. The program I'm running is computing intensive, but only needs a small portion of memory to run. What is more disturbing, is that I do not find any relevant information in the logs of the scheduler.

Comment: @Juan: you'll need to be a little more specific and show code to someone if you hope to get a diagnosis of the problem. Without that, this is just looking like an issue with torque on your end.

Comment: you need to ask the admin for more information from the logs.